# Place hyperlinks in CodeMirror textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I am new to codemirror.

I have a string in CodeMirror textarea. I want my text to be hyperlinked and it goes to a jsp page and fetch answers and append it back in the codemirror textarea.

I have tried using

`<a href="abc.com">hyperlink </a>.`

It prints everything along with the tags.

How to place hyperlinks in codemirror text area. A code snippet is really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand right, you want to change CodeMirror so that hyperlinks work in the editor as well? Could you describe a little in details what's the idea behind? It might be possible but also conficts with the idea of the editor where you edit code or html in this case instead of having it's functionality. You might find this in Microsoft Word or Excel where clicking on a hyperlink opens a link and a long click enters edit mode but it would be of greater effort to achieve it in CodeMirror.

Comment: I am developing a code editor. My requirements are as follows: I have a list of names of functions that has been made already somewhere else(not only in code editor). Now whenever a function uses it in its definition I want a hover functionality in the editor so that it underlines the function name that has already been made, plus when clicked it appends the code in the editor itself to view (or some further use). I have made the functionality to get the code and what to do about it. I just want to modify editor for further view enhancement. You can see this in eclipse IDEs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds interesting. If you add some code to show where you got stuck, you have a better chance to get some substantial help.

Comment: Actually, I am looking for functions from code mirror that allows hover functionality. If I am able to write the function to get the mouse position and especially output from it like from getCursor() I can do further operations. I just need that allows hover operations. I am trying to figure out the hover functionality but not written code for it. I know coordsChar and getTokenAt functions but we have to click it first. Hover I am not able to figure out

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for a very very delay update. Had got a work around at that time. Thought of sharing it.

Since I was looking at some code functions in this edtitor, on double click a function name I am able to append that code definition at the end of the editor.

Below is the example on how I have achieved:

```
// setup and fetched the editor earlier.
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(key)); // Got my editor


// Later on placed a double click logic:
editor.on("dblclick", function(){    
    if(editor.somethingSelected()){
        var from = editor.getCursor("from"), to = editor.getCursor("to");
        if( from.line!=to.line){
            alert("No word");
        }
        else{
            var word = editor.getRange(from, to);
            $.ajax({
                url : "hyperlink.jsp",
                data:{
                    keyword1 : word,
                },
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.length>6){
                        editor.setValue(editor.getValue()+"\n\n\n#"+word+":\n"+response);
                        var line = maxLineNumber;
                        formatMyEditor(); // Formatting my new code
                        editor.indentLine(maxLineNumber-5, -3);
                        editor.setCursor(line+2);
                    }
                    else{
                        alert(word+" -- Not in DB");
                    }
                }
           }
     });
}
```